# Retrieving value using get() with coffeescript and Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ajax, get

I'm trying to create code that will retrieve a value from another page and put it into a textbox.
However, the value is returning [object Object]

The page that i'm trying to get a value from is just a blank page with only one sentence, such as "blue shirt". The page is displaying the text, so i just need to be able to retrieve it and put it into the textbox.

Here is the code i'm trying to use:

```
  jQuery ->
    $("#productID").change ->
      productURL = '/sales/update_item/' + $('#productID').val()
      productDescription = $.get (productURL)
      $("#description").val(productDescription)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass $.get with a callback, i.e

```
jQuery ->
  $("#productID").change ->
      productURL = '/sales/update_item/' + $('#productID').val()
      productDescription = $.get productURL, {}, (data, response) ->
        $("#description").val(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.get()` is Asynchronous (*and it return's jqXHR object not the data returned by get request*)

You need to do this -

```
$.get(productURL,function(productDescription){
  $("#description").val(productDescription);
});
```

Docs `--->` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: Thanks for helping! But it was translating this to CoffeeScript which I didn't understand